# How to create .dwp WebPart in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: web-part

I need to know how to create a web part with visual studio 2010 and deploy it with a solution package in a feature.

When I try to do it by just changing the .webpart file to a .dwp file and change the markup in a corresponding way, I get an error in while deploying, probably because my elements.xml where the module is falsely  defined.

I don't know where the .dwp file is put and how to reference it? It doesent seem to go where the .webpart file normally goes "14\Features\MyFeature\ClassName".

If I knew where the .dwp goes and how to reference it in my module element I think my top question can be answered.

If anyone wonders why I need to make the wep part a dwp, its because it inherits from the "AggregationWebPart". The root problem may lay somewhere there actually.

Comment: Why do you want to make it a DWP file?  Is there something with a .WEBPART file you are unable to do?

Comment: 1.Try create DWP using WSP builder  2.Save default AggregationWebPart.dwp from webpart gallery and edit it. Then, after you deploy your wsp, add dwp to the webpart gallery manually first.

Comment: this link will be helpful.. http://onlinecoder.blogspot.in/2012/06/incompatible-webpart-markup-dwp-vs.html Hope it works

Answer (score 2):

This link might help you out: http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2012/06/incompatible-webpart-markup-dwp-vs.html

"Both .dwp and .webpart file types are used to describe where the code is for a web part. They are XML web part descriptors deployed with the web part. The difference is .dwp was the file extension used in version 2 of SharePoint and .webpart is a new extension used in version 3."

Answer (score -2):

Go through the link thsi may help..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584160%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.